Can　近く modify an adjective to mean "almost adjective"?

図書館からの道筋をもう一度たどりなおして、二人は一時間近く暗い通路をさまよった。
They re-traced the route from the library one more time and wandered the (almost/nearby) dark corridors for an hour.

I don't know if 近く means nearby (the library), or whether it is modifying 暗い to mean "almost (close to) dark". I'm favouring the former option since I haven't heard that 近く can modify adjectives in this way, but I'm not certain.

The phrase to focus on is 一時間近く

一時間近く is the phrase you want to focus on.

They retraced the route from the library once more, and wander for almost an hour down the dark corridors.

or possibly "about an hour".  Either way the meaning is that they wandered for close to an hour.

Ah, the hidden third option. Thanks.
